# CSS styling of <UL> as table

Tags: javascript, html, css

I want to use  element-loops to create a table.
I put one  for every row and put a  around it all, like this:

**HTML:**

```
<div class="tableEmulator">
   <ul class="trEmulator">
      <li class="tdEmulator">Some text</li>
      <li class="tdEmulator">Some text</li>
    </ul>
    <ul class="trEmulator">
      <li class="tdEmulator">Some text</li>
      <li class="tdEmulator">Some text</li>
   </ul>
</div>
```

**CSS:**

```
.tableEmulator {
    width: auto;
    height: auto;
    border: 1px solid;
    border-color: blue;
}
.trEmulator {
    clear:both;
    border: 1px solid;
    border-color: red;
    with:auto;
}
.trEmulator li {
    list-style:none;
    float:left;
    position: relative;
    padding: 5px 10px;
    border: 1px solid #eee; 
}
```

However I´m stuck in css trying to make to outer border of my table.
I expected width/height: auto; would do the trick, but it doesn´t. Any suggestions?

Thanks in advance!

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/AsleG/baLhx3v0/

Comment: Hi, make sure you include relevant code in the question body for brevity :)

Comment: Djjez, @Sippy… really?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try using CSS flex.

updated example:
http://jsfiddle.net/baLhx3v0/5/

```
.tableEmulator {
    display: inline-flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    border: 1px solid;
    border-color: blue;
}
ul.trEmulator {
    display:flex;
    clear:both;
    border: 1px solid;
    border-color: red;
    width:auto;

}
.trEmulator li {
    list-style:none;
    position: relative;
    padding: 5px 10px;
    border: 1px solid #eee; 
}
```

You can find more about Flex here: https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/

Comment: Thanks, @Eyal. I´ll look into flex. However removing  float:left; from the ".trEmulator li "-styling breaks the table structure, and reintroducing it takes me back to Sq.1.

Comment: @AsleG That's strange, the styling of the table itself looks the same in the example I provided, the flex styling takes care of it. Are you sure assigned the class to ul.trEmulator and not just trEmulator?

Comment: Which browser are you using @Eyal? I´m on Safari 6.1 and when I open your link I get 4 rows and I column whereas my initial fiddle is 2x2.

Comment: @AsleG I see, my mistake, I indeed only coded it for chrome. For safari you need to use "display: -webkit-flex;" and "-webkit-flex-direction:column". You can use mixins to make it work for all browsers, see here: https://dev.opera.com/articles/advanced-cross-browser-flexbox/

Comment: I got it to make the horizontal borders right, but the width is still full length. Am I doing something wrong?  Updated fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/AsleG/baLhx3v0/6/

Comment: @AsleG You just need to add the display: -webkit-inline-flex to the tableEmulator class and it should work. I also don't know if u want 'ul' as columns or rows, so both options are here in comments: http://jsfiddle.net/baLhx3v0/7/

Comment: The -webkit-flex-direction:column; and   flex-direction: column; was missing, and did the trick. Good work! Thanx! :D

Comment: @AsleG No problem. Don't forget to add -moz-flex and -ms-flex so that it will work for other browsers.

Answer (score 0):

If you set the width/height auto he'd take all avaible space that where left. In your link I'd set the width to ~200px and I think that is what you wanted.

Be sure that he'd only get so much space from inherit element that he'd can only get so much space he had to use.

(With this you can give him the auto option of course)

Comment: @Broken_Dust, I don´t want to fix the width, I want the <div> to act as a container of the <ul> and the <ul>s as containers of the <li>, so that the outer border always adjust dynamically and automatic.